# Using a filter on a time series graph with OR statement

Tags: looker-studio

I have a time series graph in Google Data Studio that connects to Search Console. In the graph I have a filter to only show search "queries" featuring a certain phrase. It works fine when I use one query. In the image I've blanked out the term as it's a clients brand name.

[image: query 1]
[image: working graph]

However when I add an OR element and then a second query the time series chart breaks.

When I add the second query it shows the error "Data Studio Cannot Connect to Your Data Set".

query 2:
[image: query 2]

Error message:
[image: error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried it out earlier today using a [Filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066), and [`REGEXP_MATCH`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7064476) with a Pipe operator

```
|
```

For example, if you are searching for a Query that contains X or Y or Z, this does the trick:

```
Include Query RegExp Match .*(X|Y|Z).*
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell you why - but I can tell you what's causing it and how to get round it.
The Search Console data source doesn't recognise the 'or' condition in the filter. To have an 'or' condition you need to add it as regex in your first condition

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you explain how that looks in the filter?